# Multiple options from one drop down giving alternate results - Javascript/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to have separate sections of my form become visible dependant on the selection from a drop down menu.

Currently i'm having two issues, its only hiding the first area i want hidden and also i'm struggling with the syntax to get the multiple options working using if statements.

Am i looking at this the right way or is there an easier way of doing this.

In the code below i've only got 2 if statements as i've been struggling to get that correct so haven't done it for all 8 options i need to.

```
function showfield(name){
    if (name=='Supplier meetings') {
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";

        if (name=='Product meetings') {
            document.getElementById('div2').style.display="block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('div2').style.display="none";
        }
    }
}

function hidefield() {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div4').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div5').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div6').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div7').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div8').style.display='none';
}
```

in my html i have:

```
<body onload="hidefield()">

<select name="acti" value=""    onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="1">Worked hours</option>
<option value="2">Overtime</option>
<option value="3">Sickness</option>
<option value="4">Unpaid leave</option>
<option value="5">Compassionate leave</option>
<option value="6">Holiday inc bank holidays</option>
<option value="7">Team meetings</option>
<option value="8">One to ones</option>
<option value="9">One to one prep</option>
<option value="10">Huddles</option>
<option value="Supplier meetings">Supplier meetings</option>
<option value="Product meetings">Product meetings</option>
<option value="Training/coaching">Training/coaching</option>
<option value="Handling other peoples cases">Handling other peoples cases</option>
<option value="15">Project work</option>
<option value="16">Surgery time for GK</option>
<option value="17">Letter checks and feedback</option>
<option value="18">MI/Reporting/RCA</option>
</select>
```

Then divs that contain the parts i need displayed off each option.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use jQuery here or you want JS only solution?

Comment: I can use either, i'm currently teaching myself javascript and have been researching the best way of doing it, but open to suggestions if there is a better way.

Comment: Ok, so basically you want to show a `div` based on the selection made, and hide all other `divs`?

Comment: Yeah exactly, sounds so easy but it is alluding me at present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing condition for each option value, you can use the value directly in selecting the `div` that is to be shown:

```
function showfield(name){
    hidefield();
    document.getElementById( 'div-' + name).style.display="block";
}
```

For this to work, your id's should match up with corresponding `option` values.

e.g. `<option value="1">1</option>`
corresponding div:
`<div id="div-1"></div>`

Comment: This has worked perfectly, i've had to add divs for options i didn't need them for as it threw up an error but i've left them blank, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `data-div` attribute to every option which will be `ID` of respective `div` which will be shown and other divs will be hidden.

You need a class on every `div` so they can be hidden using that class name except the div which will be shown based on selection.

**HTML**

```
<select name="acti" value="" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option value="1" data-div="one">Worked hours</option>
  <option value="2" data-div="two">Overtime</option>
</select>

<div id="one">First Div</div>
<div id="two">Second Div</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showfield(val)
{
  var divID = $("select[name=acti]").find("option[value='" + val + "']").attr("data-div");
  $(".divClass").hide();//You can also use hidefield() here to hide other divs.
  $("#" + divID).show();

}
```